# Azure Graph API Event filter not finding events, always blank

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to filter events using the transactionID that I used to create the event, but when I filter, it always comes up blank

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/b3255f69-88be46aad08c/calendars/AAMkADE0NzMyZDcwLTAxOTg1AAA=/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'Integer {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e} Name transactionid' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) eq 51686)`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to filter the events by transaction Id .

I tested the same by filtering creation date time and transaction Id. For creation date time it succeeded and transaction Id it failed as it's not supported.

`TransactionId`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{id}/events?$filter=transactionId eq null
```

[image]

`CreationDateTime`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{id}/events?$filter=createdDateTime eq 2021-11-04T15:08:27.9058547Z
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply,  I am using the singleValueExtendedProperties not just a regular filter
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @KenN, even if you are using singleValueExtendedProperties & not just a regular filter , the filter on transanction Id Property has been restricted by Graph API . So , regular filter shows you the error and singleValueExtendedProperties filter runs successfully with no output.